# Pandas - expanding group by / group by + expanding window on whole dataframe (all columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of the following structure (the time columns are actual time, in case it matters):

```
group  |  attr1  | attr2  | time1  | time2
--------------------------------------------
1      |  1      | 7      | 1      | 2
1      |  4      | 4      | 4      | 7
1      |  3      | 3      | 6      | 9
2      |  2      | 2      | 2      | 5
2      |  2      | 5      | 3      | 6
2      |  1      | 6      | 4      | 7
2      |  4      | 2      | 5      | 8
3      |  6      | 7      | 6      | 10
```

What I would like to do is the following:

1. Group by `group`
2. For every group data frame:

   2.1. Apply expanding window on the whole dataframe (all columns)

   2.2. For every 'expanding' dataframe

   ```
    2.2.1. Filter the 'expanding' dataframe using time1 & time2 columns (e.g. `df[df[time1]<df[time2]]`)
    2.2.2. Perform various aggregations (ideally using `.agg` with `dict` argument, as there are many different aggregations for many columns)
   ```
3. The output has basically the same number of rows as the input

My problems are:

1. I don't see a way to specify 'expanding grouping column'. If that was possible, then I could do something like:

```
def func(group_df, agg_dict):
   group_df_filtered = filter the dataframe on time columns
   return group_df_filtered.agg(agg_dict)

df.groupby(['group', expanding(1)]).apply(func, agg_dict=agg_dict)
```

2. I don't see a way to perform expanding operation on the whole dataframe. If that was possible, I could do:

```
def func(group_df, agg_dict):
    for col, funcs in agg_dict:
        agg_dict[col] = [lambda df: f(df[df[time1]<df[time2]]) for f in funcs]

    return group_df.expanding(1).agg(agg_dict)

df.groupby('group').apply(func, agg_dict=agg_dict)
```

I found a workaround that works similarly to the second approach, except that I pass whole columns to the `func` and do subsetting (as I have the whole column instead of just the expanding part) and filtering inside the function, but it's terribly slow, mostly due to the fact that I'm wrapping functions together and have a lot of custom code.

Is there a nice and most importantly, a **fast** way to achieve the functionality I need? I guess it would require as little pure python code as possible to work relatively fast (one of the reasons I use `agg` and `dict` instead of e.g. doing apply row by row or something similar, that would kill the performance, the other reason is I have multiple functions for different columns, so implementing that by hand every time would be way too verbose).

Comment: The question is a bit vague, but I think you can do for example `df.loc[df['time1'].lt(df['time2'])].groupby('group').expanding(1).agg({'attr1': [lambda x: x.max()-x.min(), 'sum'], 'attr2':'std'})`, then some reindex to able to fit the original index.

Comment: @Ben.T I cannot do that, I need to do the filtering within the groups.

Comment: Because the filtering depends on the groups?

Comment: As @Ben.T suggested you can `reindex` after applying `groupby` + `expanding` and probably  do`ffill` to fill the missing values  i guess that should work..

Comment: @Ben.T exactly because of that. In more detail, I actually do something like `df[df[time1] < df[time2].max()]` for every grouped dataframe. Perhaps I should edit the question to make that more clear.